# java app, thread hangs after killing MySQL connection

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I have some worker threads running, with MySQL and mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.
When I kill some SQL statement ( using kill "connection id" from mysql client), the java thread hangs, which should throw some exception.

jstack prints:

```
    "quartzBase$child#45e3dd3c_Worker-3" prio=10 tid=0x00007f960004c800 nid=0x713d runnable [0x00007f943b3a0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAvailable(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.available(PlainSocketImpl.java:472)
        - locked <0x00007f9e11fe13a8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(SocketInputStream.java:217)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.available(ReadAheadInputStream.java:232)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.clearInputStream(MysqlIO.java:981)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2426)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
        - locked <0x00007f9e17de2b50> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollbackNoChecks(ConnectionImpl.java:4863)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4749)
        - locked <0x00007f9e17de2b50> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.rollback(DelegatingConnection.java:368)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.rollback(PoolingDataSource.java:323)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:217)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:196)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:676)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:845)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:822)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:430)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:112)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy1021.process(Unknown Source)
```

Using jvmtop, I saw this:

```
JvmTop 0.8.0 alpha - 22:48:37,  amd64, 24 cpus, Linux 2.6.32-35, load avg 11.53
 http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop

 Profiling PID 27403: com.caucho.server.resin.Resin --root-dir 

  36.41% (     0.22s) com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.available()
  33.42% (     0.20s) ....opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultTypeConve()
  30.17% (     0.18s) com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill()
   0.00% (     0.00s) com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom()
```

The worker threads will never accept new tasks.

any idea?

Comment: *When I kill some SQL statement ( using kill "connection id" from mysql client)* when you kill a SQL statement like this for who knows why, a kitten die too =\

Comment: Why should it through an exception? If you kill the query from the side, I suspect the java thread to wait for Godot ...

Comment: hi @LuiggiMendoza , when a task is canceled, the SQL it fired on MySQL won't stop executing. So we have the statement killed.

Comment: @Fildor when connection was killed, I should see something like "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 15,277 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 15,275 milliseconds ago." and the worker will end the task with an error state, then it can receive new tasks.

Answer (score 0):

According to MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html) "kill connection thread_id" should terminate the connection associated with the given thread_id. But it looks like that is not happening (in which case the Java thread will wait for an answer forever). Maybe you can verify that the connection is actually closed using some network tool (e.g. netstat) .

I've ran into hanging MySQL connections before and had to resort to using the [socketTimeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) JDBC connection parameter (but be careful: the socketTimeout needs to be larger than the time it takes to complete the longest running query). You could also try to use the [QueryTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout%28int%29) for a prepared statement.